# how can I make dropdown elements unselectable, but can visible?

Tags: unity, unity-ui

[image]

this is basic dropdown Ui object

I want to make it ,if I click dropdown, show every elements but

can only select top element others not.

like this image, because I made tutorial.

[image]

how can I restrict other element to select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your custom drop down and setup Interactable to false for options  you are not able to select. Or you need to modify Dropdown script, better copy it and rename then setup Interactable opiton for your items list.

Comment: Create custom drop down from scratch is the easiest way to do this task. You probably won't need all the features of Unity dropdown.

Comment: This answer would be more useful if it explained how to create a custom drop down from scratch.

Comment: Thnaks to reply answer. I will try do that

Answer (score 0):

[image]

On picture DropDown - button OnClick -> DropDownFields->gameObject.Active(true);
Green Red Blue - fields with buttons. when onClick->{SelectFieldAction();DropDownFields->gameObject.Active(false)}
To DropDownFields you need to add components ContentSizeFilter and VerticalLayoutGroup.
And you have custom ScrollDown you can add as many field as you need and setup Interactable for each button true of false.